# JavaFX add list of event handlers to canvas

Tags: java, javafx

I need to help with pattern for adding event handlers from list to Canvas. I have CanvasController which includes Canvas. Than I have ToolController which includes buttons, each button has List of specific event handlers. After clicked on these button is sent List to CanvasController and change listener added or removed events to Canvas. Do you think that approach is good ?

Comment: At the first read I think the two controllers are super tighly coupled. I guess it some kind of drawing application. Your "canvas" could have it's own model storing a serializable representation of the current state of the canvas, and the other controller could set the properties of the model (draw-mode, text-mode ...) and then on changes of these properties the controller of the model could decide what should happen with the GUI classes.

Comment: @Pornosaurus Nope. Better use the strategy pattern. This way you've got the behavior of each tool in a seperate class and you do not need to swap the event handlers - you just need to delegate to the strategy...

Comment: @fabian Thank a lot. I think that I use this pattern but not properly. I have `abstract class ToolButton `with this method `abstract List getEvents()` and each button extends the abstract class and must overlay the method for get their important events. For example: `class ToolSelect` has events for selecting objects on canvas, scrolling to zooming on canvas, etc.. So in the get method has something like this: `List getEvents() { return List.addAll(click, zooming, ...); }'. And after if you clicked on any button list is sent to CanvasController to save it to his list and then added to Canvas.

Comment: @fabian If I understand is better remember which button is selected and each new created Canvas only get his Events by method ?